# Why can't i inherit the value of number 3 in the class add2?

Tags: java, inheritance

How can I inherit the value of number3 from class Add to its subclass Add2?

The current output in this program is

```
6
7
```

> The class Add2 is ignoring the value of number 3.

My expected output is:

```
6 
10
```

My code:

```
class Operation{

    public int number1;
    public int number2;

    public Operation(){}
    public Operation(int n1, int n2){
        setperson(n1,n2);
    }
    public void setperson(int n1, int n2){
        this.number1=n1;
        this.number2=n2;
    }
    public int getNumber1(){
        return number1;
    }
    public int getNumber2(){
        return number2;
    }
    public void result(){
        System.out.println("The result is " + (this.number1 + this.number2));
    }
}

class Add extends Operation{

    public int number3;
    public Add(){}
    public Add(int n1,int n2,int n3){
        super(n1,n2);
        setAdd(n3);
    }
    public void setAdd(int num3){
        this.number3 = num3;
    }
    public int getNumber3(){
        return number3;
    }

    public void result(){
        System.out.println("Result is " + (this.number1 + this.number2 + this.number3));
    }

} 

    class Add2 extends Add{
    public int number4;
    public Add2(){}
    public Add2(int n1,int n2,int n3, int n4){
        super(n1,n2,n3);
        setAdd(n4);
    }
    public void setAdd(int num4){
        this.number4= num4;
    }
    public int getNumber4(){
        return number4;
    }
    public void result(){
        System.out.println("Result is " + (this.number1 + this.number2 + this.number3 + this.number4));
    }
} 


    public class taskthree{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Operation sum = new Add(1,2,3);
        Add2 sum2 = new Add2(1,2,3,4);
        sum.result();
        sum2.result();
    }

}
```

Comment: `Add2` overrides the `setAdd` method; so when `Add2`'s constructor calls `Add`'s constructor, and `Add`'s constructor then calls `setAdd`, it's calling `Add2`'s version of `setAdd` (which sets `number4` in `Add2`), **not** `Add`'s version  (which would have set `number3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I debugged your program and what happened was that `setAdd(int num3)` inside

```
Add(){
    super(n1, n2);
    setAdd(n3);
}
```

constructor was calling `setAdd(int num4)` of `Add2`. That happened because you initialized `sum2` of `Add2` and `Add2` class's `setAdd(int num4)` was overriding `setAdd(int num3)` in parent class because both methods have same method signature `int setAdd(int)`. So `sum2.n3` was never assigned `n3` of the arguments.

Instead you should do something like

```
public Add(int n1, int n2, int n3) {
    super(n1, n2);
    this.number3 = n3;
}
```

inside `Add` class and

```
public Add2(int n1, int n2, int n3, int n4) {
    super(n1, n2, n3);
    this.number4 = n4;
}
```

inside `Add2` class. Or change method names.